# Why does my org-link-beautify extension generate many timers?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

I wrote an extension [org-link-beautify](https://github.com/stardiviner/org-link-beautify). It uses text properties to
display all-the-icons icon for links.
When I use `list-timers`, I found many timers like this:

UPDATED of command `list-timers` (show more link path in hash-table)

```
1179.80          -    #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode
-0x120012ba5f9562c1> [#<hash-table equal 1440/1642 0x1565afccff6b>
("-1003358868.jpg" :v-adjust 0.01) remhash])
1179.80          -    #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode
-0x11c7991bee93a665> [#<hash-table equal 1440/1642 0x1565afccff6b>
("1004068059.jpg" :v-adjust 0.01) remhash])
1179.80          -    #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode
0x1d09e6f58d6a9d3f> [#<hash-table equal 1440/1642 0x1565afccff6b>
("-1004540555.jpg" :v-adjust 0.01) remhash])
1179.80          -    #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode
-0x728e7a4499562c5> [#<hash-table equal 1440/1642 0x1565afccff6b>
("-1010525956.jpg" :v-adjust 0.01) remhash])
1179.80          -    #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode
-0x8917a573e9562c5> [#<hash-table equal 1440/1642 0x1565afccff6b>
("-1011541969.jpg" :v-adjust 0.01) remhash])
       1h 54m 24.9s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x15627c2da862a7a4> [#<hash-table equal 236/325 0x157dcf12ae9d> ("https://www.zhihu.com/question/281992632/answer/612244555" :v-adjust -0.05) remhash])
       1h 54m 24.9s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x185dd8418bb95f95> [#<hash-table equal 236/325 0x157dcf12ae9d> ("https://www.zhihu.com/question/312702679/answer/648228648" :v-adjust -0.05) remhash])
       1h 54m 24.9s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1543f4c7ed08f637> [#<hash-table equal 236/325 0x157dcf12ae9d> ("https://www.zhihu.com/question/19918564" :v-adjust -0.05) remhash])
       1h 57m 50.2s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1624e8d5c40e6cd7> [#<hash-table equal 236/325 0x157dcf12ae9d> ("https://wangdoc.com/ssh/" :v-adjust -0.05) remhash])
       1h 57m 50.2s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1d58d576aa4ef853> [#<hash-table equal 236/325 0x157dcf12ae9d> ("https://emacs-china.org/t/linux-kvm-windows/15134" :v-adjust -0.05) remhash])
       1h 57m 50.3s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x33bd87bdd6ddd93> [#<hash-table equal 236/325 0x157dcf12ae9d> ("https://www.douban.com/gallery/topic/720/" :v-adjust -0.05) remhash])
       1h 57m 50.3s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x63ad8d9a555e907> [#<hash-table equal 83/97 0x157dcf01dea5> (".org" :face org-link :v-adjust 0) remhash])
       1h 57m 50.4s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x12ca43d2c81e6703> [#<hash-table equal 83/97 0x157dcf01dea5> ("Computer Todos.org") remhash])
       1h 57m 56.6s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode 0x1681d642b3ef7697> [#<hash-table equal 83/97 0x157dcf01dea5> ("init-emacs-appearance.el") remhash])
       1h 58m 14.6s            - #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0xf96db9ba05420ab> [#<hash-table equal 83/97 0x157dcf01dea5> ("init-emacs-frame.el") remhash])
```

The more Org mode buffers opened, the more timers created.

I'm wondering iff there is a problem in my [source code](https://github.com/stardiviner/org-link-beautify/blob/master/org-link-beautify.el) - or maybe this is a mechanism in Org Mode?

Can you tell me how these timers were created? And how to avoid creating them in my extension?

Comment: I have many Org mode buffers open and I don't see any timers (other than known ones). Do you see those timers if you don't load your extension? If not, then you can definitely blame your extension (which BTW is always the more likely explanation for weird behavior like this - otherwise, there would be a flood of bug reports on the Org mode list which I know you are subscribed to :-)  ). Of course, it might be some *other* extension that you have added that causes this: starting with `emacs -Q -l minimal-init.el` file should allow you to check this.

Comment: I confirm my extension `org-link-beautify` generated those timers. But don't know why. I used use minimal Emacs config to test my extension. And double checked my extension implementation source code. Have not found any clue.

Comment: What about `all-the-icons`? Have you done a minimal example where you just load that?

Comment: `all-the-icons` just display text-property with font icons. Should not genertae timers. I tested and confirmed terminal emacs also have those timers.

Comment: But it seems to go out and grab fonts or something (I haven't looked in any detail). Maybe it doesn't start anything after it is set up, but something is happening during its setup.

Comment: No, I use `all-the-icons` in other places, have not seen those timers.

Comment: Today, I dig into all-the-icons source code, have not found any clue about hashed icons or generated timers.

Comment: @NickD You're right. After somebody's hint, I found `all-the-icons` indeed caused those timers by using `memozie` library.